# Erro de redirecionamento de site

Tags: php, htaccess, redirecionamento, redirecionamento-de-url, redirect

Meu site sempre redireciona de `www.idealnutri.com/magnesio-dimalato` para `www.idealnutri.com/magnesio-dimalato/` (COM BARRA NO FINAL). Por que?

Como saber o que esta ocasionando este redirecionamento?

OBS: Não tenho HTACCESS no meu site.

Comment: Qual seria o inconveniente da barra no final?

Comment: Quando você não coloca o nome do arquivo na url o navegador busca na pasta ( a ultima no url `magnesio-dimalato`  ) por um arquivo .ìndex.html`ou ``index.php` ou etc.. (tem uma ordem de predominância). Portanto o navegador coloca automaticamente a barra para referenciar a pasta e em seguida procurar pelo arquivo predominante.

Comment: @LeoCaracciolo Tem como votar negativo em comentário? rs

Comment: @dvd tem sim, mas porque?

Comment: É isso mesmo, só up nos comentários. Ajuda ai no linguajar da minha resposta aqui. Pode editar!!!

Comment: Deyvison Silva, seja bem-vindo. Não deixe de ler esses posts: aceitar resposta https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1078/como-e-por-que-aceitar-uma-resposta/1079#1079  exemplo minimo https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve e como não fazer perguntas https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5483/manual-de-como-n%C3%83o-fazer-perguntas/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quando você não coloca o nome do arquivo na url o navegador busca na pasta (a última no url `magnésio-dimalato`) por um arquivo padrão `index.html` ou `index.php` ou `default.php` etc.. (tem uma ordem de predominância). Portanto o navegador coloca automaticamente a barra para referenciar a pasta e em seguida procurar pelo arquivo padrão.

Um exemplo online bem simples acessando esse link `http://dominio.com/sos` vai ver que o navegador colocou a barra no final e vai buscar pelo arquivo `index.html`. Portanto digitar `http://dominio.com/sos` ou digitar `http://dominio.com/sos/index.html` ou ou digitar `http://dominio.com/sos/` leva ao mesmo destino.

Porém se não houver o arquivo padrão dentro da pasta, vai aparecer uma listagem com todos os arquivos da pasta.

**Sobre URLS**

[image: url]

A primeira parte de um URL é o protocolo, que informa a um navegador qual serviço da Internet deverá ser usado para transferir o documento. Um protocolo é separado do restante do URL por dois pontos.

Exemplos de protocolos mais utilizados:

- ftp - os servidores FTP são depósitos de arquivos, tais como, documentos, sons, figuras, programas de computador etc..
- mailto - indica transporte de correio eletrônico.
- http - obtém informações dos servidores da Web. Este é talvez o protocolo mais comum que você irá encontrar ao surfar na Web.
- https - cria uma conexão com um servidor da Web seguro, e depois criptografa todas as solicitações de páginas e informações.

A segunda parte, que aparece à direita do protocolo, identifica o servidor no qual o documento se encontra armazenado. Observe que você tem de separar o protocolo do servidor Web com duas barras.

A terceira parte define a localização exata do documento, isto é, identifica as pastas ou subdiretórios que contém a página ou arquivo. Se uma página ou arquivo estiver armazenado na pasta raiz de um servidor, seu URL não possuirá um caminho.

**A quarta parte de um URL é o nome do arquivo**. Se não incluir o nome do arquivo específico, o  navegador procura por uma página padrão e a ordem que o servidor utiliza para procurar a página é a seguinte:

- Windows 2003 -IIS 6 : index.htm, default.asp, index.html, default.htm, index.shtml, index.wml, default.aspx, index.asp, index.php.
- Windows 2008 -IIS 7 : index.htm, index.html, default.htm, index.shtml, index.wml, default.aspx, index.asp, index.php, default.php
- Windows 2008 -IIS 8.5 : index.php, index.asp, default.asp, default.aspx, index.htm, index.html, default.htm, index.shtml

***Exemplo Windows 2008 -IIS 7***

Se dentro do diretório `magnésio-dimalato` existir uma página "default.asp" e também "index.htm", o servidor exibirá a "index.htm".